# How do I remove roads from Mathematica maps?

Tags: geography

I'm using `GeoGraphics` and `Polygon[Interpreter["USState"]["Colorado"]]` to create a map of Colorado and several bordering states.  With automatic GeoStyling, I get a decent map with cities and roads indicated.

I am plotting some data points on top of this map.  This unfortunately makes the map difficult to read -- it's rather busy.  Is there a way I can remove the roads from this map (keeping the cities and state borders)?

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[Automatic], Polygon[Interpreter["USState"]
["Colorado"]]}, GeoRangePadding -> Quantity[150, "Kilometers"], 
GeoProjection -> "Mercator", ImageSize -> {800}, GeoScaleBar ->  
Placed[{"Imperial", "Metric"}, Scaled[{0.05, .96}]]]
```

I used `GeoBackground->GeoStyling["StreetMapLabelsOnly"]` to get rid of the roads (keeping the cities), but it also got rid of the state borders.

I feel like I am almost there! Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: You might wish to search simultaneously for roads and maps on this site.

Answer (score 6):

To get the state borders, one can overlay an `"OutlineMap"` on top of a background with `GeoStyles["SreetMapLabelsOnly"]`. The key is to ask for a map that is big enough to catch all of the states you want to see, and then specify

1. the center of the area of interest via `GeoCenter`
2. the range of the area you want to plot via `GeoRange`
3. the level of detail via `GeoZoomLevel` and `ImageSize`

Perhaps something like this will work:

```
GeoGraphics[
 {GeoStyling["OutlineMap"], Opacity@0, Polygon[Interpreter["USStateClass"]["WesternStates"]]},
 GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["StreetMapLabelsOnly"],
 GeoCenter -> Interpreter["USState"]["Colorado"],
 GeoProjection -> "Mercator",
 GeoRange -> Interpreter["USState"]["Colorado"],
 GeoRangePadding -> Quantity[150, "Kilometers"],
 GeoScaleBar -> Placed[{"Imperial", "Metric"}, Scaled[{0.05, .96}]],
 GeoZoomLevel -> 7,
 ImageSize -> {600}
]
```

> [image: map]

#### Notes

1. Since the only control one has over the level of detail is via `GeoZoomLevel`, which can be finicky, and `ImageSize`, expect some odd features, such as city names covered by state lines or a floating "United States" label in Kansas. If one goes too high in zoom level, road route symbols are also displayed, although there are no roads to match them to.